# Spring jpa performance the smart way

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a service that listens to multiple queues and saves the data to a database.

One queue gives me a person.

Now if I code it really simple. I just get one message from the queue at a time.
I do the following

1. Start transaction
2. Select from person table to check if it exists.
3. Either update existing or create a new entity
4. repository.save(entity)
5. End transaction

The above is clean and robust. But I get alot of messages its not fast enough.

To improve performance I have done this.
Fetch 100 messages from queue
then

1. Start transaction
2. Select all persons where id in (...) in one query using ids from incomming persons
3. Iterate messages and for each one check if it was selected above. If yes then update it if not then create a new
4. Save all changes with batch update/create
5. End transaction

If its a simple message the above is really good. It performs. But if the message is complicated or the logic I should do when I get the message is then the above is not so good since there is a change some of the messages will result in a rollback and the code becomes hard to read.

Any ideas on how to make it run fast in a smarter way?

Comment: Message parsing , validation is something that has to be performed every time. Its does not matter you execute messages one by one or in batches. 
You can add exception handling and instead of rollback just put bad messages in different queue  to be handled by some other logic or send alert.

Comment: Hi Satyendra. The reason taking one message at a time is slow is because of all the roundtrips to the database. Thats why its faster to select everything I need with one query and updating everything with one update in a batch. But you are right, validtion and message parsing has to be done everytime but thats not where the time is used.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to rollback? Can't you just not execute whatever it is that then has to be rolled back?

IMO the smartest solution would be to code this with a single "upsert" statement. Not sure which database you use, but PostgreSQL for example has the `ON CONFLICT` clause for inserts that can be used to do updates if the row already exists. You could even configure Hibernate to use that on insert by using the `@SQLInsert` annotation.